# One directory up from current directory C++ (Sqlite)

Tags: c++, database, sqlite, path, directory

There's probably a simple solution to this but I just can't find it.

When I open my application I want to open an sqlite database one directory up from the current directory the program is running from.  It is the 'Database' directory.
This is the relevant lines of code. Nothing else matters at this point.
The database doesn't open.  Don't want to create a database, I want to use an existing one.

```
string d_base  = "Database/settings.db";

if(SQLITE_OK == sqlite3_open_v2(d_base.c_str(),&handle,SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE ,NULL))
{
  // does something.
}
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29

Comment: Does `../Database/settings.db` do what you need?

Comment: This worked in the end.     "./Database/settings.db"   Kabdulla you were close.  The wiki page seemed to refer to command lines but I'm sure the answer was in there somewhere.